# Reference request for definitions of belief

Tags: reference-request, definitions, belief

There is a lot that has been written about knowledge in the philosophical literature. However, I am interested in a simpler concept, namely belief. I want to read some texts on the definitions of belief that philosophers have given. I would love to see some references.

Comment: Where have you looked for references so far?

Comment: [Belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/)

Comment: A work now a couple of decades old was Sam Harris's The End of Faith.  Harris defined belief as a judgement call to adopt a viewpoint based on some degree of reasoning and evidential justification, while in contrast faith is to adopt a viewpoint without any such justification.